# Is there a better way to do this jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery but i am really liking it.

I have some jQuery as below that works as expected, i am jsut wandering if there is a more effective less resource hungry method to do the same thing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("select.openTime").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != 'Closed') {
                $(this).next(".hidden_element").css('display', 'block');
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'Closed') {
                $(this).next(".hidden_element").css('display', 'none');
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions welcome.
Thanks
M

Comment: How resource hungry is your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, less DOM parsing.

```
var state = $(this).val();
var $next = $(this).next(".hidden_element");
```

DOM access is your most resource heavy operation. Minimize reference/scanning the DOM as much as possible. Also, make it easier by adding unique ids rather than classes for each block if you can. Maybe this is not the design...

Second, use classes or the show()/hide() methods.

```
if(state == "CLOSED") { 
  $next.hide();
  // or...
  $next.addClass('hidden');
} else
  $next.show();
  // or...
  $next.removeClass('hidden');
}
```

Note: this is simple enough to make a clean ternary statement:

```
(state == "CLOSED") ? $next.hide() : $next.show();
```

That will reduce your conditional logic a bit as well as reduce your calls to search the DOM.

The end result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("select.openTime").change(function() {
            var state = $(this).val();
            var $next = $(this).next(".hidden_element");

            (state == "CLOSED") ? $next.hide() : $next.show();        
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: an overall fantastic response, thanks to everyone for there suggestions. Lukas your suggestion seems the best option overall, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions

1. Use an ID rather than a tag/class selector as the underlying getElementById is more efficient
2. Rather than display block/none - why not try .slideToggle() or fadeToggle() - check these out at http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is a *little* more efficient and more readable:

```
$(function(){

    $("select.openTime").change(function() { 
        var $nextHiddenElement = $(this).next(".hidden_element")
        
        if ($(this).val() != 'Closed') {   
            $nextHiddenElement.show();
        }
        else {   
            $nextHiddenElement.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use `else` for a start.  Or better still, just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(function() {
    $("select.openTime").change(function() {
        $(this).next(".hidden_element").toggle($(this).val() != 'Closed');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in raw javascript. Just add the following script to the `onchange` of your `select` elements:

```
var current = this.nextSibling;
while(current){
    if(current.className='hidden_element'){
        if(this.value == 'Closed'){
            current.style.display = 'none';
        }else{
            current.style.display = 'block';
        }
        return;
    }else{
        current = current.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks good to me, you could also use the built in show and hide functions which might make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's so resource hungry about this..  I fixed your conditional though:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.openTime").change(function() { 
        if ($(this).val() == 'Closed') {    
                    $(this).next(".hidden_element").css('display','none');
            } else {
                    $(this).next(".hidden_element").css('display','block');
            }       
    });
});

</script>
```

Also:
`css('display','none');` can be changed to `hide();`
`css('display','block');` can be changed to `show();`

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be very resource heavy.  The only thing I would change is to use show() and hide() instead of the css() call.

```
$(this).next(".hidden_element").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("select.openTime").change(function() {
      var object = $(this);

      if (object.val() != 'Closed') {
          object.next(".hidden_element").css('display', 'block');
      } else {
          object.next(".hidden_element").css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thank should lighten up your resources.

Hope that helps.